# Python - Writing a dictionary of dictionaries to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm new to python and made a simple scraper that will log into several analytics accounts and print some data to a CSV. The format I'm printing to CSV in is a dictionary that I create with the following code:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
import time
def save_file(website, visitors, links, sources):
    date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    d = OrderedDict()
    d['Title'] =  website    # website string
    d['Date'] = date         # date string
    d['Vistors'] = visitors  # integer
    d['Links'] = links       # dictionary of links - URL : Clicks
    d['Sources'] = sources   # dictionary of sources - Source: Clicks

    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Traffic Report.csv')
    with open(path, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, d, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(d)
```

When I print to CSV using this code, the site, date, and visitors cells work great. The links/source cells (data I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape) are full of extra quotation marks and characters as seen below.

```
{"['www.example1.com/']": '1', "['www.example2.com']": '1', "['www.example3.com']": '1', "['www.example4.com/']": '3', "['www.example5.com/']": '1'}
{"['Links']": '2', "['Social media']": '5', "['Direct']": '2', "['Searches']": '1'}
```

[image]

Is there any way to remove many of these characters and print to csv as: 
www.example1.com : 1, www.example2.com : 1, www.example3.com : 1...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do the formatting yourself. Instead of a dictionary, build a string:

```
d['Links'] = ', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(*item) for item in links.items()])
d['Sources'] = ', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(*item) for item in sources.items()])
```

This produces `link1: count1, link2: count2` results.

As a sidenote, you don't need to use an `OrderedDict` object here, just give the `DictWriter` a sequence of keys in the order you want them written instead. I'd also open the CSV file just *once* outside the loop:

```
d = {
    'Title': website,
    'Date': date,
    'Visitors': visitors,
    'Links': ', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(*item) for item in links.items()]),
    'Sources': ', '.join(['{}: {}'.format(*item) for item in sources.items()],
}

path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Traffic Report.csv')
with open(path, 'a') as f:
    fields = ('Title', 'Date', 'Visitors', 'Links', 'Sources')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(d)
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, is there any benefit to using the method you provided for preserving the print order over using an ordered dictionary or is your solution just standard practice?

Comment: It's the standard practice; it also allows you to ignore other keys on the dictionary, and leave other keys empty and have `csv.DictWriter()` leave the column blank for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(dct):
    return ", ".join("%s : %s" % (key, value) for key, value in dct.iteritems())
```

(use `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()` if Python3.x) and then

```
d['Links'] = convert(links)
d['Sources'] = convert(sources)
```